# Three.js: Build-in way to add object with bottom in z = 0

Tags: three.js

Is there a **build-way one-liner** in three-js to add object to 'bottom' of the scene - with z = 0 corresponding to the bottom of the object (the bottom of the object's bounding box) instead of default's object centered in origin?

I know we can achieve this by adding the half of bbox's height to the position like:

```
const addToBottom = (scene: Three.Scene, object: Three.Object3D) => {
    const bbox = new Three.Box3();
    bbox.setFromObject(object);
    scene.add(object)
    object.position.z += (bbox.max.z - bbox.min.z) / 2
}
```

Comment: something like that: `object.position.z += new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object).getSize().z * 0.5;`. I'd put `THREE.Box3()` in a variable for re-use and have a variable for the size for re-use too.

Comment: @prisoner849 makes sense

Comment: @prisoner849: since there are no more responses, mind making it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner can be like that:

`object.position.z += new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object).getSize().z * 0.5;`

Comment: r139

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry;
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.position.z += new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( cube ).getSize().z * 0.5;

three.module.js:5645 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subVectors')
    at Box3.getSize (three.module.js:5645:58)